# How to get only the last token using StringTokenizer in java

Tags: java

I want to get only the last token from stringTokenizer
See below is my code:

```
String assetClasses = "Gold:Stocks:Fixed Income:Commodity:Interest Rates";
StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(asseltClasses, ":");
while (token.hasMoreElements()) 
{
    System.out.println(token.nextToken());
}
```

My expected output is:

```
The last token is : Interest Rates
```

Comment: You may think the lengthy while loop is not good, but the old-fashioned can be much faster comparing to "split" especially you need to deal with a large amount of data.

Answer (score 5):

Not very efficient to parse the entire string.

Instead you can use something like:

```
int index = assetClasses.lastIndexOf(...);
String token = assetClasses.substring(...);
```

Check out the `String` API for the parameters required for each of the methods.

Answer (score 3):

You can use split method in String class to achieve this, can get the last token without iterating through the whole loop.

```
private String getLastToken(String strValue, String splitter )  
{        
   String[] strArray = strValue.split(splitter);  
   return strArray[strArray.length -1];            
}
```

Comment: You don't have to iterate, but you still have to parse the entire string.

Comment: I find this solution to be the most intuitive I've seen, which is worth a lot in my opinion. Helps with understandability.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to use StringTokenizer, just iterate over the elements, and take the last token while ignoring others:

```
String lastToken = null;
while(token.hasMoreElements()) {
    lastToken = token.nextToken();
}
```

Otherwise, in addition to other answers here, you can consider using StringUtils class from Apache Commons:

```
String lastToken = StringUtils.substringAfterLast(asseltClasses, ":");
```